# PDF viewer which can move files to folder easily

Tags: pdf-viewer

I'd like to scan through a large set of PDFs and move them to given target folders (in Windows or Linux) depending on the content. So the key is to have a shortcut for moving the currently viewed PDF to a folder.

I could use Irfanview for that, which does exactly this, but Irfanview is kinda slow for PDF viewing and page scrolling.

Do you know an alternative?

Comment: Which mode/function in IrfanView has that functionality?

Comment: Irfanview can show PDFs. It also can move files easily by pressing F7 and a selection from your folder list by a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware of that powerful dialog box to move files to different pre-defined folders.  Learn something new every day!

Comment: (Near-on-topic rant.) In my dreams, every window that shows/edits a file content shows an icon you can drag-n-drop to any file manager window just as if you had dragged it from another file manager window.  Also, any program that shows/edit files has a drop zone where you can drop icons from any file manager window.  Doubting that it is better? Hint: file selector/save windows tend to replicate file manager functionalities. Need to save in a new dir? Here's a "new dir" button. Need to rename existing target to avoid overwrite? Here's a "rename" feature. All in the file load/save window...

Answer (score 2):

I would write a simple shell script which would be structured like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(command to get a list of all the pdf files I want to check)
mypdfreader="command for the pdf reader I want to use"
function getNewLoc {
    newlocation=$(some command which returns the new location, for example a zenity dialog)
    #OR
    read $newlocation
}

for file in $files; do
    mypdfreader $file
    getNewLoc
    mv $file "$newlocation"/
done
```

That way when you close the pdf viewer with some keyboard shortcut you are automatically asked where to put the file. Maybe there would also be a nice bash-file selector, but I don't know one.